# Blogdown, .Rmd files, and id Attributes

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am working on a [website](https://slu-soc5650.github.io) for an upcoming course that I teach, and I've run into an issue. I am not sure whether the issue is with my theme, Hugo, or blogdown.

Normally, my theme takes second-level headers (`##`) and adds `id` attributes that are linked to on the left-hand navigation menu when the specific page is opened: see [this working example, where the four second-level headers all appear on the menu](https://slu-soc5650.github.io/course-preview/).

However, if I use a `.Rmd` file to generate the page rather than an `.md` file, [this functionality stops working](https://slu-soc5650.github.io/lecture-01/). I need the `.Rmd` file to be able to embed maps produced with leaflet on the page.

Looking at the generated `.html` source, the `id` attributes are still generated for all of the second-level headings, but the `#second-level` `.html` file is not being generated. Thus the [headings are still visible on the left-hand menu](https://slu-soc5650.github.io/lecture-01/) but their link is not functional.

Is there a workaround for this? I've poked around here and elsewhere and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/58) is the closest I've come to my issue. Thanks to anyone who has some ideas - it is much appreciated!